# TLS communication between MSK and kafka throws error when InsecureSkipVerify is set to false

Tags: go, apache-kafka, sarama

I am using sarama clib want to enable TLS communication between my component and MSK ! setting up InsecureSkipVerify to true makes it work, but with false it fails with the above error.
Btw, MSK has no ACM attached and Im using its TLS endpoint.
I am using TLS MSK endpoints

```
        type Config struct {
    ConsumerBrokers []string       `envconfig:"consumer_brokers"`
    ProducerBrokers []string       `envconfig:"producer_brokers"`
    ClientConfig    *sarama.Config `envconfig:"client_config"`
    ConsumerTopic   string         `default:"Firehose" envconfig:"consumer_topic"`
    ConsumerGroup   string         `default:"router" envconfig:"consumer_group"`
    ProducerPrefix  string         `default:"" envconfig:"producer_prefix"`
    LogLevel        string         `default:"info" envconfig:"log_level"`
    HttpAddr        string         `default:":8080" envconfig:"http_addr"`
}
        var conf Config
        conf.ClientConfig = sarama.NewConfig()
        tlsConfig := tls.Config{}
        conf.ClientConfig.Net.TLS.Enable = true
        conf.ClientConfig.Net.TLS.Config = &tlsConfig
        conf.ClientConfig.Net.TLS.Config.InsecureSkipVerify = false
    }
```

Logs

```
{"level":"panic","method":"main","msg":"kafka: client has run out of available brokers to talk to (Is your cluster reachable?)","package":"main","time":"2022-10-19T14:36:46Z"}
```